# how to count collection.defaultdict values?

Tags: python, collections, set

I have a file with `type`= `collections.defaultdict`

it is like this:

```
defaultdict(set,
            {'2712': {'java', 'manager', 'program', 'programme', 'senior'},
             '3193': {'agile', 'coach', 'master', 'scrum'},
             '2655': {'business', 'consultant', 'principal'})
```

I have never worked with this type. How I can count each elements for each keys? for example for '2712' is 5 for `3193` is 4 and for `2655` is 3.

Comment: iterate over dict (key, value) and get `len(value)`. What is unclear? What have you tried and have problem with?

Comment: so should I have `for I in dict(key,value): g=len(value)` ?

Comment: @buran could you please help me out?

Comment: No. `dict` is a "special" word (you can redeclare it, but do not do it :-) The code should be `d = defaultdict(...)` `for key,value in d.items(): g=len(value)`. Or `for value in d.values(): g=len(value)` if you are not interested in keys. See Luke Storry's answer, "you can use a default dict in the same way as a normal dict"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for `defaultdict` say, you can use a default dict in the same way as a normal dict, using the square brackets for indexing for keys, and iterating through the list of keys with a for loop, as below:

```py
d = defaultdict(
    set, {
        '2712': {'java', 'manager', 'program', 'programme', 'senior'},
        '3193': {'agile', 'coach', 'master', 'scrum'},
        '2655': {'business', 'consultant', 'principal'}
    })

for key in d:
    print(f"The set at key {key} is {len(d[key])} long.")
```

See repl [here](https://repl.it/@LukeStorry/65809960#main.py)

Answer (score 1):

```
for key, value in some_dict.items():
    print(f'{key}: {len(value)}')
```

where `some_dict` is your dict/defaultdict.